# Different query results using * and column names

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

When using * and column names differently, the query result is different in both the cases. There is a possibility that only the order is different but why is that as we haven't used any command to sort the data.

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

[image]

But when I query, the first_name, last_name column:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees;
```

[image]

Lastly when I add a column that has an index on it,

the result is different again

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name,last_name FROM employees;
```

[image]

Why is the result is different?

I couldn't understand how first_name, last_name column values are ordered.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: without use of order by no ordered  is guaranteed so use order by in your query

Comment: Is employee a table or a view?

Answer (score 1):

The data is the same, just in a different order.

What I will add is that it looks like you have an index on `(last_name, first_name)`.  What is happening in your case is that Oracle recognizes that it can use this index for the query -- it is a *covering index*.

That is why the results with just those two column names look like they are ordered.  Of course, you cannot depend on this.  Results sets are *unordered* unless an `order by` clause is explicitly included in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

only use of order by can guarantee to show in a specific order

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name,last_name FROM employees order by first_name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the DBMSs store data not necessarily ordered. When you run a query, dbms uses an execution plan for better performance and how to collect data. So there is no guarantee that you get same ordered data each time. Instead use `order` command to get what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

**Data is stored in un-ordered set in tables in Oracle.**

So when you do `select *` or `select column_names`, data may retrieved in different order but data is not different. It is something like you are looking at only 50 rows and comparing.

If you want the consistent data then you must have to use same `ORDER BY` in both the queries and you will find same data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have at least two indexes, one on employee_id and the other on last_name.
in the first select:

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

the data came ordered by employee_id.
on the second select:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees;
```

the data came ordered by last_name.
on the last one:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name,last_name FROM employees;
```

the data came ordered by the primary key index employee_id ,Which seems have higher priority by default, just like the first select.

to be sure how the data returns use "order by".